# Problema al instalar Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy

Hola buenas estoy intentando instalar la librería kivy para python mediante pip con python 3.12. Ya lo había instalado de esta manera en la versión 3.11 sin ningún problema. Pero cambié de pc y actualicé las versiones de todo. dejo abajo el comando que usé y el output de la terminal:

```
pip install kivy[full]
```

output:

```
Collecting kivy[full]
  Using cached Kivy-2.2.1.tar.gz (24.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Obtaining dependency information for setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/3a/5121b58b578a598b269537e09a316ad2a94fdd561a2c6eb75cd68578cc6b/setuptools-69.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
        Using cached setuptools-69.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Obtaining dependency information for wheel from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/c3/55076fc728723ef927521abaa1955213d094933dc36d4a2008d5101e1af5/wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
        Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting packaging
        Obtaining dependency information for packaging from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/1a/610693ac4ee14fcdf2d9bf3c493370e4f2ef7ae2e19217d7a237ff42367d/packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
        Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.33,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl (987 kB)
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Obtaining dependency information for kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/e3/6e4d32636a39bf25a83fa956373805b494d95c77a57cf021971da000d3e8/kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
        Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (215 bytes)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.6.0 (from versions: 0.7.0)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.6.0

      [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
      [notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Lo curioso es que generalmente con este tipo de errores (los que te dicen que no tiene que ver con pip) te dan una pista de lo que causa el problema y a menudo un link a donde ir para solucionarlo. Si alguien sabe porqué pasa esto, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Kivy aún no soporta Python 3.12. Más información: [1](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8391), [2](https://github.com/kivy/kivy#kivy) y [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/17ufpz9/ive_spent_hours_attempting_to_install_kivy_and_it/)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es actualizar el pip. Esto se hace con el comando:

python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip.
Copia y pega en el cmd de tu dispositivo

Comment: Espero que te sirva de algo, a mi me pasaba lo mismo y se solucionó al actualizar el pip

Comment: hermano lo intenté, pero el resultado fué igual excepto que ya no me pide actualizar pip. Igual lo que había hecho fue descargar python 3.11 y correrlo así. Gracias por el comentario